How does one replicate a session cache in jboss 7.4?
I have question for you about caching...
I have this java app that I am trying to run on a jboss EAP 7.4 cluster. Cache the login sessions, and i notice this weird error....
18:28:04,609 ERROR [org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl] (default task-18) ISPN000926: afterCompletion() failed for SynchronizationAdapter{localTransaction=LocalTransaction{remoteLockedNodes=[oss7-4-6949c7fcb7-ck7q6, oss7-4-6949c7fcb7-qm99h], isMarkedForRollback=false, lockedKeys=[], backupKeyLocks=[], topologyId=5, stateTransferFlag=null} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SyncLocalTransaction@74} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter@93: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Could not commit.
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletionStages.join(CompletionStages.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.afterCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:34)
    at org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.notifyAfterCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:505)
    at org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.runCommit(TransactionImpl.java:331)
    at org.infinispan.commons.tx.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:107)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache.tx.TransactionalBatch.close(TransactionalBatch.java:98)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.session.oob.OOBSessionAttributes.setAttribute(OOBSessionAttributes.java:90)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.setAttribute(DistributableSession.java:228)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.setAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:169) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener.syncSessionScopedBeans(WebappLifecycleListener.java:361) [jsf-impl-1.2_12.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener.requestDestroyed(WebappLifecycleListener.java:101) [jsf-impl-1.2_12.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.requestDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:273) [jsf-impl-1.2_12.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.requestDestroyed(ApplicationListeners.java:289) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:330) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100) [undertow-servlet-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393) [undertow-core-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852) [undertow-core-2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.2.32.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_222]


I have this cache config in my standalone.xml file, which times out after 60 seconds. Which should be sufficient for the replication to occur.
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:12.0">
            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="dist" aliases="sfsb" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" aliases="singleton cluster" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="default">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="sso">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </replicated-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="routing"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" modules="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="pending-puts">
                    <expiration max-idle="60000"/>
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                </local-cache>
                <invalidation-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" striping="false" acquire-timeout="60000" />
                    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </invalidation-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>


Is there a better way to replicate the application session cache in a jboss cluster?
In the war file, i have this config, which enables the replication of the app....
jboss-web.xml
...

<replication-config>
    <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
    <!-- <replication-granularity>ATTRIBUTE</replication-granularity> -->
</replication-config>
```

web.xml
``` 
...

<distributable/>

...

```

So the application boots fine, without any issues, but when i attempt to login, It crashes really quickly... Has anyone manged to replicate session data in an successfully ? 


Ta,

X

